# How to use the class path of filesystem without including the complete filesystem header in C++17?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, filesystems

I have two questions :

First question :

I want to create an object of type

```
std :: filesystem :: path
```

I wish to do it without going through boost, because the standard C 17 allows this.

the advantage with boost is that we can do:

```
#include <boost / filesystem / path.hpp>
```

So it allows you to include exactly what you want.

But if I do at the beginning:

```
#include <filesystem>
```

then in this case, it includes a large portion of code that will not be used (but I am not sure of this claim), in the code after processing.

So, my first question : Is it possible to include only the class "path" of filesystem with C++17 standard ?

I watched :

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem

And there are plenty of classes I do not need. I only need "path".

How can I integrate only path, without involving boost?

I guess, in case it's possible, that the using if filesystem in C 17 reduces the code obtained after pre-processing ?

Thank you

Comment: The compiler will throw away anything that’s not used basically, so the only advantage would be possibly for compile time. Most likely the standard doesn’t provide any way to just include a specific class, compiler vendors might

Comment: _"...it includes a large portion of code that will not be used, in the code after processing..."_ do you have any evidence for this?  Remember to check with a release build.

Comment: Classes that you do not use should be optimized out in a release build.  If your compiler/linker does not dead code strip unused classes, send your compiler vendor a problem report.

Comment: Not possible. But also not an issue. An include file *declares* things, it does not *define* anything. If you don't *use* those declared things, there would be no effect on final executable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard requires that `path` is at least forward declared in `<filesystem>`, see: [29.11.5 Header `<filesystem>` synopsis](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.filesystem.syn). In practice, it will depend on your compiler where `std::filesystem::path` is declared, and because of that, you should just include `<filesystem>`.

I was also under the impression that only having to include `<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>` would be cheaper in terms of compile time than having to include 'all of' `<fileysystem>`, but measuring it gives surprising results, at least on my machine, for `std::filesystem`:

```
$ echo '#include <filesystem>' | time -p g++ -std=c++17 -x c++ -c -
real 0.49
user 0.43
sys 0.05
```

versus only including `<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>`:

```
$ echo '#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>' | time -p g++ -std=c++17 -x c++ -c -
real 0.89
user 0.81
sys 0.07
```

So including `<filesystem>` is almost twice as fast as including 'only' `<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>`. To further solidify that the increase in compile time can be attributed to the Boost implementation rather than some other obscure reason, I checked the number of header files that need to be preprocessed as a consequence of including `<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>` and `<filesystem>` respectively:

```
$ echo '#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>' | g++ -std=c++17 -x c++ -M -c - | wc -l
407
```

versus:

```
$ echo '#include <filesystem>' | g++ -std=c++17 -x c++ -M -c - | wc -l
144
```

I think it is safe to conclude you do not have to worry about including `<filesystem>` if it is compile times you are worried about.